# How to propose a recurrence equation for a given DFA over a set of q states?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence, finite-automata, dfa, formal-languages

I am trying to solve question 2 on the following link: [Check out Q.2](http://staff.polito.it/silvano.rivoira/FormalLanguagesCompilers/AutomataHomeworks/Gradiance%20Online%20Accelerated%20Learning1.htm).

That is I am interested in the number `N(k)` of binary strings of length `k` accepted by the following deterministic finite automaton (source: the URL).

[image: Finite state automaton]

For example `N(2)=2`, as only such strings are `01` and `10`. In particular I am interested in a recurrence relation for `N(k)`.

Comment: We want questions to be self-contained.  Please edit your question to include the full text of the question you're asking, and what you've tried.

Comment: Plz check this link http://staff.polito.it/silvano.rivoira/FormalLanguagesCompilers/AutomataHomeworks/Gradiance%20Online%20Accelerated%20Learning1.htm

Comment: The question i have asked is a general approach to solve similar problems.

Comment: @SouravMishra is a recurrence enough or are you looking for a closed-form solution?

Comment: @blazs thnx for the solution.

Comment: @blazs your solution serves the purpose but let me know if there is a closed-form solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recurrence is `N(k) = 2*N(k-3) + N(k-2)` for `k>=3`, with the boundary conditions `N(0)=N(1)=0` and `N(2)=2`.

The reason is that given an acceptable string `w` (by acceptable I mean a string that the DFA accepts), you can either extend it with `11` to "remain" in the final state or add either `010` or `001` (both of length 3) to "remain" in the final state; the recurrence follows directly from these observations (think about it).

As an example, here's the first few strings of lengths `k=2,3,...,7` accepted by the automaton:

- For k=2 the solutions are `01`, `10`.
- For k=3 there are no solutions.
- For k=4 the solutions are `0111`, `1011`.
- For k=5 the solutions are `01001`, `01010`, `10010`, `10001`.
- For k=6 the solutions are `011111`, `101111`.
- For k=7 the solutions are `0100111`, `0101011`, `1001011`, `1000111`, `0111001`, `0111010`, `1011001`, `1011010`.

We can see that the recurrence correctly counts the number of solutions:

- N(3) = 2*N(0) + N(1) = 2*0 + 0 = 0.
- N(4) = 2*N(1) + N(2) = 0+2 = 2.
- N(5) = 2*N(2) + N(3) = 2*2 + 0 = 4.
- N(6) = 2*N(3) + N(4) = 2*0 + 2 = 2.
- N(7) = 2*N(4) + N(5) = 2*2 + 4 = 8.